# Gradient ends are blurry when using pixel measurements

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm using  the `background-image: linear-gradient` css property to create multiple color strips for a site background.
Usually gradient stops are defined by percentage, but I needed pixels in my site, so I managed to change it to pixels using the method lea Verou used in her [patterns](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#tartan)
The problem is that the end of each color is a bit blurry. In Firefox it's less noticeable, but in Chrome it's very noticeable.
Is there a way to handle it?
I noticed that when I change the 'deg' from 180 to 45 the ends look great. But unfortunately I need the stripes to be horizontal :)

My code: http://cssdesk.com/c6mGM

Comment: Really weird, when i add the -webkit- prefix to the linear-gredient it switches from horizontal to vertical

Comment: changing from 180 deg to 270 deg and it's horizontal. Or 'top' instead of the 'deg'

Comment: @Rachelbt, Have u checked my solution?

Comment: @Rachelbt Try to replicate it here http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I'm familiar with this tool but it generate only percentage stops and not pixel stops:(

Comment: This is due to a bug in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140208

Comment: Here in 2021 and still have issues in Chrome. Don't know if this will work for everyone, but I was able to resolve my issues by using something similar to the answer below: `background-position-x: right` or `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Answer (score 9):

Almost a year later and I run into the same bug in chrome v36.  I produced a work around here: http://codepen.io/davidgailey/pen/ncrKB

or here if you prefer:
https://gist.github.com/davidgailey/8fc1bd1a09747429a3ad

The work around uses background-size, background-position, and linear gradients.

```
background-size: 100% 150px, 100% 150px;
background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom;
background-image:
linear-gradient(#000,#000),
linear-gradient(green, green);
```

Viola! nice crisp horizontal stripes. It could use some work to be more future-friendly.

I hope this bug is fixed soon but in the mean time, feel free to use my pen as a start.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! This worked pretty well, though I'm using more than two gradients and I'm getting a 1px blur between some of them. Not entirely noticeable though... I guess I'll wait for the Chrome fix.

Comment: Chrome 56 should have this fix. Due out in a month or so. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140208

Comment: I created a Scss mixin to generate the background image/size/position from a dynamic list of colors: https://gist.github.com/stroebjo/e4339b09d939cdcb353caf8ca34a18e1